# Set up : Buy 1 Get 1 free (the same product)

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

Could you explain me step by step how to set up a Buy 1 Get 1 Free promotion from the shopping cart price rules menu.
Ex: If customer buy 1 pack of cookies he gets another 1 for free.

I've tried by my own it doesn't work properly and i guess i can do it without buying specific extension.

Comment: I don't think you can do this out the box. The main issue would be gifting the same product (same sku?) at a 0 price. Funny that this question just popped up. I just made this possible in my gifting extension, upon request from a client and is currently undergoing testing for release.  (not released yet) - called Buy X get X free

Comment: Hi, in case you are interested, I have the feature on a demo store: http://giftpromo.proxiblue.com.au/ - simply add any item, and it will be gifted automatically. Same sku, same item, at $0

Comment: Can now be seen live, on client website :) - https://www.zabadaclean.com/kitchen-care.html - just add an item to cart, and see it gifted immediately, for free.

Comment: I've found the way to do it with a shopping cart price rule. It works perfectly now. Everything can be set without dedicated extension.

Comment: Nice. Do you mind sharing? place as self accepted answer. It will help someone down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope my answer will help anyone who want to set up a buy x Get y free on Magento:

1st. Go to **Promotions** > **Shopping cart prices rules**

2nd. Click on Add new rule

3rd. Define a name, a short descritpion, select website and customer groups

4th. Define if your promotion require a coupon to be activated or not

5th. Define a period

6th. **Conditions** : nothing to set up here

7th. **ACTIONS** :

a> Select "Buy x Get Y free"

b> Discount amount put "1" (that means 1 prodcut free)

c> Maximum qty discount apply : Select how many times in the order this promotions can be applied

d> Discount qty : Put "1" for a Buy 1 get 1 Free or put "3" to apply a buy 3 get 1 free

8th. **Rule to apply to cart items** : clik on SKU and type the sku of the product concerned by this promotion.

So basically, if you have set up a Buy 3 get 1 free promotion for example, you customer my need to add 4 products in his cart, then he'll get a 100% on one of these products.

Feel free to ask for more details.

Comment: If you do this for 3 get 1 free, it only applies for the first 3 right? If I would get 8 I only get 1 for free?

Comment: @eric Ly  i'm trying the same but not working.   also check sku attribute value for promotion rule   use magento 1.8.1

Comment: @lalitmohan is this working for you?

Comment: No this didn't work for me.

Comment: If you prefer third-party solutions for this kind of conditions, I suggest using the Special Promotions Pro (https://goo.gl/jYPgcS) from Amasty.